# several choices for executable path, but only one works inside Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to register my executable for some shell action and need to find out the path to current executable. I found several questions (and answers) here on SO, and found the following options:

- `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]`
- `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName`
- `typeof(Program).Assembly.Location`

However when debugging inside Visual Studio 2010 the first two return the vshost exe name, e.g. `...bin\Debug\ExportVSProject.vshost.exe`. I think I understand why. By trial-and-error I found that the last provides the right name inside VS and outside.

My question is, are there any downsides to using `Assembly.Location`? The reason I am asking is I did not see any comparison to choose one over the other in the other answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine.  The more general solution is Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location, usable anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, I like your better because next time I cut and paste I don't need to change the type name, which was the one issue had with my solution :)